# Two corrupted indexes found by DBCC CheckTable

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering if this problem is solvable by dropping/recreating the two indexes.  Both are rarely used, nonclustered, non PK, non FK indexes.

Here is the dbcc output:

> Table error: table 'Items' (ID 1954106002). Data row does not have a matching index row in the index 'IX_Advertise_BrandCopy_Price_Stock' (ID 69). Possible missing or invalid keys for the index row matching:
>
> Msg 8955, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Data row (1:11226494:9) identified by (Id = 11078215) with index values 'AdvertiseFlag = 1 and BrandCopyParentId = 0 and NSFPPrice = 137.50 and NSFPQtyInStock = 0 and Id = 11078215'.
>
> Msg 8951, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Table error: table 'Items' (ID 1954106002). Data row does not have a matching index row in the index 'IX_ITEMS_ADVFLAG_PARETN_PRICE_STOCK' (ID 70). Possible missing or invalid keys for the index row matching:
>
> Msg 8955, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Data row (1:10834009:15) identified by (Id = 8885719) with index values 'AdvertiseFlag = 1 and BrandCopyParentId = 0 and NSFPPrice = 9.30 and NSFPQtyInStock = 0 and Id = 8885719'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-clustered indexes can always be recreated from the base table. No need to drop them [just rebuild the](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx)m:

```
alter index IX_Advertise_BrandCopy_Price_Stock on BrandCopy rebuild;
```

Of course, you must figure out *how* did they end up corrupted. Is Windows reporting IO errors? Does your drive firmware report errors? You need to investigate to figure out what is causing the corruptions and eliminate the problem (likely faulty hardware, disk or memory).

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience with corruption, I've always had to drop and recreate nonclustered indexes, as the rebuild plan uses an index scan (of the corrupt index) because it's cheaper than scanning the base table -- the corruption has always remained every time I've tried this.

Comment: Yes the issue returned shortly after.  I have our sysops people running diagnostics on the (possibly) faulty hardware, tickets open with the IO Vendor, and, just in case, a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: @JonSeigel: yes, you are right. Rebuild will use the same index as source and will keep the corruption, since is a cross key issue. Aushin, try drop and create...

Answer (score 3):

I would back up the db, then drop & recreate those corrupt indexes. Then run the same dbcc periodically to checkup on the problem.

Comment: This sounds sensible, but I'd prefer it if you weren't user2154687.  Are there any risks to the dropping and recreation of corrupt indexes?  I would prefer not having to perform a full restore.

Comment: Since they are non-clustered, in my experiences, they are more for speed then integrity of the table. The only issue with recreating non clustered indexes, is the speed of your applications(s) while recreating them. The size of the tables determine how long it will take to recreate them; also if your application/users are putting locks on the tables(inserts/updates) while your are doing the reindex. Sometimes after hours is the best time.