# Database corruption extends beyond nonclustered index issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

## Background

I have a server running SQL Server 2008 R2 on the matching MS OS. Over the last few months this server had a RAID drive failure on two separate occasions (which simply required hotswapping a new drive and re-building the RAID), but that did not affect the database itself which is running on an SSD on a different RAID cluster.

1) I have an error in an index where the index value for a column is invalid and does not match the actual data

2) I probably have other errors that aren't being properly diagnosed by DBCC CheckDB, as I had a query fail that **DOES NOT** use the corrupt index.

## Issue 1 (solved by comment [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36498/two-corrupted-indexes-found-by-dbcc-checktable#comment64684_36500))

Note: this issue is addressed by the comment [linked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36498/two-corrupted-indexes-found-by-dbcc-checktable#comment64684_36500), but is left for context as to issue 2. Plus, I have to drop and re-create the index still;)

This is from `DBCC CheckDB`

```
Msg 8951, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: table 'TidBitData' (ID 1835869607). Data row does not have a matching index row in the index 'I_TBD_Fn' (ID 8). Possible missing or invalid keys for the index row matching:
Msg 8955, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Data row (1:3867082:9) identified by (Date_Time = '2011-09-04 22:02:49.000' and TidBit_SerialNum = 1232451) with index values 'Filename = '2012 T1 tidbit`1232451 Antioch North_12T1.csv' and Date_Time = '2011-09-04 22:02:49.000' and TidBit_SerialNum = 1232451'.
Msg 8952, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: table 'TidBitData' (ID 1835869607). Index row in index 'I_TBD_Fn' (ID 8) does not match any data row. Possible extra or invalid keys for:
Msg 8956, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Index row (1:6267114:32) with values (Filename = '2012 T1 tidbit`1232451 AntⅩoch North_12T1.csv' and Date_Time = '2011-09-04 22:02:49.000' and TidBit_SerialNum = 1232451) pointing to the data row identified by (Date_Time = '2011-09-04 22:02:49.000' and TidBit_SerialNum = 1232451).
```

The following:
`ALTER INDEX I_TBD_Fn on db.schema.TidBitData REBUILD`
just changed the index row in error to (1:6630769:43) (from 1:6267114:32) for the same data row (1:3867082:9)
as reported by a re-running of `DBCC CheckDB`

## Issue 2

I initially ran `DBCC CheckDB` (for issue 1) because the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT x, y, COUNT(*) as cnt
     FROM ATable
     WHERE [ADate]>'2014-01-01' group by x, y) as bob
```

in SMSS failed with

> Msg 682, Level 22, State 146, Line 7
>   Internal error. Buffer provided to read column value is too small. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for any corruption.

No errors were returned by `DBCC CHECKDB` pointing to `ATable` (which is not the `TidBitData` table)

## Current Status

My IT staff pointed me at an [MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938697) that mentioned my issue 2 with regard to SQL server 2005 (which my database is not). The potentially relevant portion reads:

> This problem occurs because temporary tables are cached in SQL Server 2005. The cached temporary tables are reused if the table schema remains the same. However, a cached temporary table may be incorrectly reused even if the table schema has changed.

However, even assuming that the inner query was cached to the TempDB, I wouldn't expect the schema to have changed in either my database or the TempDB. This error no longer presented itself when I changed the outer portion of the query to read

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as XYGroupCount,
    SUM(cnt) as TotalRecordsInRange
FROM ...
```

I am still concerned that this error ever popped up. As I said, the database schema for neither my tempdb nor my actual database should have changed.  I ran `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS` and `DBCC CheckTable (x) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` for the two tables without error.  I then ran

```
DBCC UpdateUsage(mydb)
DBCC UpdateUsage(tempdb)
DBCC CheckDB(mydb) with ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
DBCC CheckDB(tempdb) with ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
DBCC CheckDB(master) with ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
DBCC CheckDB(msdb) with ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
DBCC CheckDB(model) with ALL_ERRORMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
```

The `DBCC CheckDB(tempdb)` appears to fail with warning but without formal error:

> DBCC results for 'tempdb'.
>   DBCC CHECKDB will not check SQL Server catalog or Service Broker consistency because a database snapshot could not be created or because WITH TABLOCK was specified.

All other databases report 0 errors. e.g.

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'model'.

## Final Thoughts/Questions

Are these issues related to the RAID drive failure?  Is there an issue with the RAM?

Comment: Hi, For your issue 2 could you please check here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/835030/SQL-ERROR-Internal-error-Buffer-provided-to-read-c

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida referring to your link: the `DBCC CHECKDB` didn't suggest a repair strategy, but after dropping and re-creating the index for issue 1, `DBCC CHECKDB` said all was well with the database. `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS` also returned with no errors.